# How to use list comprehension in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to teach myself Haskell and I am doing random exercises. 
I was supposed to write a code that will do this 6 = [1*1 + 3*3 + 5*5]= 35
So  I had to filter out all odd numbers and then calculate the sum if I multiply every single one with itself.

```
 sumquad n = (potenzsum(filter odd (ones n)))
     where
     potenzsum [x] = x*x
     potenzsum [x,y] = x*x + y*y
     potenzsum (x:xs) = x + potenzsum xs

ones 0 = []
ones x = [ 1 .. x]
```

This code works ;) 
Now I am supposed to do the same thing but with list comprehension (I am allowed to use this list [1...n]

I could only think of this... Could someone help me?

```
power1 xs = [x*x | x <- xs]
```

Comment: Your first implementation of `potenzsum` looks quite odd to me. You really want to add the squares of the last two elements to the sum of all the preceding elements, without squaring them? If so the list-comprehension approach will have to be a bit more complicated.

Comment: After the last xs of power1, add the condition after a comma `odd x'

Comment: into list compreshion at right u put the condition and left what u want to do with the result [x*x | x <- xs, (condition to check (in your case get odds))] example [x^2 | x <- [1..n], odd x]

Comment: You don't need a base case for `ones`; `[1..0]` evaluates to an empty list. Also, `ones` is a really bad name for this function, as it suggests a (possibly infinite) series of 1s (`[1,..]`), not an increasing sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you did half the job by `[x * x | x <- xs]`, just replace `xs` by odd numbers from the previous example:

```
[x * x | x <- filter odd (ones 6))]
```

And you'll receive a list of squares: `[1, 9, 25]`, which can be summed by function [sum](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum):

```
f n = sum [x * x | x <- filter odd (ones n))]
```

it evaluates to `35`

One more note regarding list comprehension: the iterated elements can be filtered out by specifying conditions, which are called guards. Thus, the code above can be refactored into:

```
f n = sum [x * x | x <- [1..n], odd x]
```